# GRUB2 does not see /boot and cannot boot

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, grub

I have changed my disk on laptop and installed Arch Linux. Everything would be ok, if it could boot normally. When I start the laptop, I see an error:

```
/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod is not found
```

and I am in GRUB rescue console.

When I type in that: `ls /boot`, I see no files, despite the fact, that the files are there in filesystem (I checked it from Linux `ls`). I found a workaround:

```
insmod /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod
normal
linux /vmlinuz-linux root=...
initrd /initramfs-....img
boot
```

but I needed to copy initramfs.. and vmlinuz.. from `/boot` to `/`

I would like to mention that /boot is not on another partition: everything is on / (/dev/sda1), and completely don't know why I cannot boot to Arch Linux. Why does GRUB2 not see /boot files?

**edited**:

I'm attaching `parted -l` command result:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
1      1049kB  246GB  246GB   primary   ext4            boot
2      246GB   250GB  4082MB  extended
5      246GB   248GB  1598MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
6      248GB   250GB  2482MB  logical   ext4            esp
```

I would mention also that three times grub booted without any problem (!).

Does it matter that I installed SSD disk?

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question and glad you solved your problem.  In this site's format, though, the way you did it will confuse people because questions are reserved for just questions and solutions go in answers.  Can you move the solution to an answer (you're allowed to answer your own question)?  Tomorrow, you will be able to accept your answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will indicate that the problem's been solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

My friend recommended to me to reinstall the system, and to make new partitions. Apparently the old partitions: /dev/sda{1,2,5,6} were wrong. It helped.